# Change color of FontAwsome Glyph

Tags: css, javafx, font-awesome

I'm using FontAwesome Glyphs in a button and want to change the color in a method. Does anyone know how to do this? I also tried "-fx-fill: black;". Both don't work.

```
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIcon;
public FontAwesomeIcon close;
close.setStyle("-fx-fill: black;");
```

Comment: try `color` it may work

Comment: setStyle("-fx-fill: black;"); is the right command to change the color. I just tried it out and it works. I used FontAwesomeIconView though. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView;

FontAwesomeIconView fa = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.CLOSE);
fa.setStyle("-fx-font-family: FontAwesome; -fx-fill: BLACK; -fx-font-size: 28px");
```

Comment: Font size and fill have corresponding functions: .setGlyphSize and .setFill

Answer (score 1):

```
import de.jensd.fx.glyphs.fontawesome.FontAwesomeIconView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox vBox = new VBox();

        FontAwesomeIconView closeIcon = new FontAwesomeIconView();
        closeIcon.setStyle("-glyph-name: CLOSE;");

        Button button = new Button("change icon color to red");
        button.setOnAction(event -> closeIcon.setStyle("-glyph-name: CLOSE; -fx-fill: red;"));

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(closeIcon, button);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer.
Where do you reckon the problem was? How do you think one can avoid this issue in the future? Help us be better, don't just give us the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
FontAwesomeIconView fontAwesomeIconView = new FontAwesomeIconView(FontAwesomeIcon.CLOSE);
fontAwesomeIconView.setFill(Color.rgb(66, 139, 202));
```

You should use `setStyle` for properties that can't be set natively.

Also size:

```
fontAwesomeIconView.setGlyphSize(Font.getDefault().getSize() * 2);
```